# How can I connect to the kathmandunet in pytezos?

Tags: python

I'm using pytezos and trying to send 1 xtz from one account to another account using pytezos and I want to do this transaction on kathmandunet and I don't know how to initialize the pytezos instance for kathmandunet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the example bellow:

```
from pytezos import pytezos
pytezos_client = pytezos.using(shell='https://rpc.kathmandunet.teztnets.xyz')
```

Comment: can you tell me that how I can find the details of a transaction by using the transaction hash in pytezos?

Comment: I have answered it in your other question. You can also use an indexer. (tzkt API should provide all the information you need https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Operations_GetTransactionByHash)

Comment: can you explain indexer?

Comment: @ShahbazAli an indexer is a very key part of working with a blockchain. If you are new to this space i'd encourage you to google some topics and do more research. Many of the questions you are asking are easily found online. e.g. here are some tezos related docs on indexer, also see the "TZKT" tab under this sub heading for further info: https://wiki.tezosagora.org/build/blockchain-indexers